# “Warning Oops, something went wrong” error while creating a Facebook Advert

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to create a Facebook advert.

When I click on the “Place Order” button, I get the following message:

> Finish Your Advert
>
> Warning Oops, something went wrong. Please try again later

Sometimes this can occur if there is an outstanding payment or there is something wrong with payment settings. I've checked both of these and all is in order.

What else may be causing this issue?

Comment: There are some generic tips on the web, but essential it all comes down to this: Contact Facebook support.

Comment: How do I contact Facebook support? I can't find a form or valid email address. There are some answers here: https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=716399758419419 but none seem to help.

Comment: Also found this link but no solution. https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=641135559266019

Comment: Emailing info@facebook.com returns this: Hi,

You've reached us at a channel that we don't support. Please visit the Help Center to find answers to many frequently asked questions and up-to-date forms you can use to get in touch with us:

https://www.facebook.com/help

We apologize for the inconvenience. 

Thanks,
The Facebook Team

Comment: Found "Report a Problem" link on normal Facebook drop down menu. http://www.wikihow.com/Contact-Facebook
Hopefully they will respond soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad was eventually placed using the Facebook Power Editor.

Simple Create Ad still not working at time of writing this.

Thanks to http://omcgroup.com.au/ for their assistance.

Answer (score -1):

I hit this problem and worked on it for a couple hours before calling it quits and heading to bed. All I had to do the next morning was resubmit it and it worked fine. (Relief! I wasn't sure what else to try.) So maybe just try later. I heard on another forum that someone fixed it by removing sound from their video ad.

Comment: Yes, just waiting some time and retry is sometimes the simple thing to do. I had the same [issue with grouping Saved Posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/125274/collection-in-saved-items-not-opening): the vague error message and no other information. After two weeks the issue was gone.